# How to turn a data.frame column into the column with the fastest changing value

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame `df1`. I want to have the column `Cycle` in `df1` changing fastest. AFAIK, `order` does the opposite? Do I need to order all other columns expect for this one?

If there is a term for this column "sorting" operation, please edit the title, I could not come up with a better word than "fastest changing" and therefore, also had issues to search for it.

```r
df1 <- expand.grid(
  Names = c("Model_1", "Model_2"),
  Batch_size = c(20, 32),
  Cycle = 1:5)

> df1
     Names Batch_size Cycle
1  Model_1         20     1
2  Model_2         20     1
3  Model_1         32     1
4  Model_2         32     1
5  Model_1         20     2
6  Model_2         20     2
7  Model_1         32     2
8  Model_2         32     2
9  Model_1         20     3
10 Model_2         20     3
11 Model_1         32     3
12 Model_2         32     3
13 Model_1         20     4
14 Model_2         20     4
15 Model_1         32     4
16 Model_2         32     4
17 Model_1         20     5
18 Model_2         20     5
19 Model_1         32     5
20 Model_2         32     5
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, it is not about setting up such a data frame. It is about "sorting" (or "unsorting" if you want) of a column of an existing data frame, so this column becomes the "fastest changing" one.

Comment: Maybe `expand.grid(Cycle = 1:5, Batch_size = c(20, 32), Names = c("Model_1", "Model_2"))[3:1]` ?

Comment: rows <- sample(nrow(df))
df <- df1[rows, ]

Comment: The first by @GKi changes the order of columns, which is not what I'm looking for. The one by Dr. Flow randomly samples rows?

Comment: No it does not change the order - or better it reorders them with [3:1].

Comment: @GKi what I'm saying is that in your comment the row ordering is already determined using `Cycle` as first parameter to `expand.grid`. I'm looking for a way to achieve this for an existing data frame.

Comment: Oh maybe you look for `df1[do.call(order, df1),]` ?

Comment: @GKi yes that works. It depends on `Cycle` being the last column, right? I'm actually surprised that there seems to be no other possibility so far than to sort all other columns first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is already present in `df1` we can arrange all the columns using

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% arrange_all()
```

Or everything except `'Cycle'` column.

```
df1 %>% arrange_at(setdiff(names(df1), 'Cycle'))
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the existing `df1`? The question is not about setting up such a data frame, but about rearranging a column of an existing data.frame so it is the "fastest changin" one...

Comment: ok, so this is what I also mentioned above. In case I had 10000 columns, I would create a names vector with all those except the one to be "unsorted"?

Comment: @crazysantaclaus Well, to be honest, you have presented your question in a confusing way. `expand.grid` has nothing to do with your question and yes, you if you have 1000 columns you can create names vector of 999 columns and sort the dataframe by it. In `dplyr`, you can do that with `df1 %>% arrange_at(setdiff(names(df1), 'Cycle'))` Or simply just `df1 %>% arrange_all()` since `Cycle` is the last column.

Comment: sorry, I honestly don't think it is confusing and I've put all this information in the description. But I've spent some time with the question now so I probably lost a feeling how it appears to others. Could you generalize your answer for a df with many columns, I will accept it! Thanks!

Comment: The `arrange_at` version is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the fastest-changing to be the first column, then I think you have a couple of options.

Starting with a simple definition of the factors:

```r
list1 <- list(
  Names = c("Model_1", "Model_2"),
  Batch_size = c(20, 32),
  Cycle = 1:5)
```

(If this is from a pre-existing frame, then one could do `list1 <- lapply(df1, unique)` to get this.)

From here,

```r
rev(do.call(expand.grid, rev(list1)))
#      Names Batch_size Cycle
# 1  Model_1         20     1
# 2  Model_1         20     2
# 3  Model_1         20     3
# 4  Model_1         20     4
# 5  Model_1         20     5
# 6  Model_1         32     1
# 7  Model_1         32     2
# 8  Model_1         32     3
# 9  Model_1         32     4
# 10 Model_1         32     5
# 11 Model_2         20     1
# 12 Model_2         20     2
# 13 Model_2         20     3
# 14 Model_2         20     4
# 15 Model_2         20     5
# 16 Model_2         32     1
# 17 Model_2         32     2
# 18 Model_2         32     3
# 19 Model_2         32     4
# 20 Model_2         32     5
```

This involves "sorting" but on the columns themselves, not the rows. That is, `rev(list1)` only works with three elements, and `rev(expand.grid(...))` also only reverses three elements (the columns of a frame).

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to sort all other columns, or if you have only one column, you can create a matrix per group holding the row-number and use them across the groups to make it change from line to line.

```
x <- split(seq_along(df1$Cycle), df1$Cycle)
df1[na.omit(c(t(sapply(x, function(y) y[seq_len(max(lengths(x)))])))),]
#     Names Batch_size Cycle
#1  Model_1         20     1
#5  Model_1         20     2
#9  Model_1         20     3
#13 Model_1         20     4
#17 Model_1         20     5
#2  Model_2         20     1
#6  Model_2         20     2
#10 Model_2         20     3
#14 Model_2         20     4
#18 Model_2         20     5
#3  Model_1         32     1
#7  Model_1         32     2
#11 Model_1         32     3
#15 Model_1         32     4
#19 Model_1         32     5
#4  Model_2         32     1
#8  Model_2         32     2
#12 Model_2         32     3
#16 Model_2         32     4
#20 Model_2         32     5
```